# Tabbed run unloaded event when change tab

Tags: c#, wpf, tabs, mdi

I have WPF form code like this (C#):

```
private void formSearch_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Publisher.dataUpdated += search;
}


private void formSearch_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Publisher.dataUpdated -= search;
}
```

When I open or change the tab to this form, `formSearch_Loaded` will run whenever I go to this tab / form, but when I change to the other tab `formSearch_Unloaded` will run automatically (basically in MDIstyle = "MDI" instead of MDIstyle = "tabbed" `formSearch_Unloaded` will run when the form closed).

How can I run this `formSearch_Unloaded` event when the tab is closed (like when I used MDIStyle = "MDI") instead of tab changed?

Comment: Can this be so? In handler close tab add call the `formSearch_Unloaded`: `private void CloseTab(){ formSearch_Unloaded(MyTabItem, null); }`?

Comment: the problem is, i don't know where is the handler, that is just default button from MDIStyle = "tabbed" that already there and close tab if clicked. I already search for the handler everywhere but i didn't get the answer.

Comment: Are u using DevExpress controls? If so there is a CloseCommand that gets or sets a command executed when an item is being closed

Comment: thx for your response guys, i found the solution now. I realize that unloaded event called twice when the tab closed. So i just need to use some flag.